# Roles in jwt token not available for Vaadin AccessAnnotationChecker

Tags: keycloak, vaadin-flow, quarkus-oidc

Latest Vaadin Flow (23.2.4), Quarkus (2.13.2.Final) and Keycloak 16.1.1.

The problem is, the roles defined in Keycloak are availalbe in the token, but not via the request that Vaadins AccessAnnotationChecker use to check access.

So, I can write my own checker, retrieving roles from the token, but I'd rather have AccessAnnotationChecker do it. I have a similar app with Spring Boot and Spring Security, and the roles are available to AccessAnnotationChecker there.

Basically I have a BootstrapCustomizer:

```
    AccessAnnotationChecker accessAnnotationChecker = new AccessAnnotationChecker();

    void onServiceInit(@Observes  ServiceInitEvent event) {
        event.getSource().addUIInitListener(uiEvent -> {
            final UI ui = uiEvent.getUI();
            ui.addBeforeEnterListener(this::beforeEnter);
        });
    }

    private void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
        accessToken.getClaimNames().stream().forEach(n -> System.out.println(n + ":" + accessToken.getClaim(n).toString()));

        System.out.println("is user in role user:" + ((HttpServletRequest)VaadinServletRequest.getCurrent()).isUserInRole("user"));
        if (!accessAnnotationChecker.hasAccess(event.getNavigationTarget())) {
            System.out.println("REROUTING ON ACCESS DENIED");
            event.rerouteTo(FlightView.class);
        }
    }
```

The printout shows the roles like this in the claim realm_access

```
realm_access:{"roles":["privileged","default-roles-xxx","User","offline_access","uma_authorization","user"]}
```

Eg. the user has the roles "user" and "privileged". I use these in the Vaadin views with @RolesAllowed({"user","privileged"}) and also in the MainView to decide if a particular menu item is to be shown, ex:

```
        if (accessAnnotationChecker.hasAccess(ProfileView.class))
            navbarTabs.add(new NavTab("Profile", ProfileView.class));
```

These are my properties

```
quarkus.oidc.client-id=my-client
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=https://xy.zzy.no/auth/realms/xxx
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=secret
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=none
quarkus.oidc.authentication.user-info-required=false

# this must be false with type=web-app, but probably is needed for roles check?
# this only works for service-applicatoins, see https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication instead
quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=false
# this is needed when backend is not https
quarkus.oidc.authentication.force-redirect-https-scheme=false
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web_app

quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.paths=/*
quarkus.http.auth.permission.authenticated.policy=authenticated

quarkus.oidc.logout.path=/logout
quarkus.oidc.logout.post-logout-path=/
```

I believe perhaps quarkus.keycloak.policy-enforcer.enable=true would do the trick, but it only works for service applications, not web-applications.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the "roles" element is too deep? You can tweak the mapper for `User Realm Role` in Keycloak to return a simpler list by changing Token Claim Name from `realm_access.roles` to `groups` for example. Setting `Multivalued` `On`/`Off` may change things as well.

Client scopes > Client scope details > Mapper details > User Realm Role